# ksh regex - how to insert variable

Tags: regex, variables, ksh

**Ksh** regex problem  (i can do a similar script quite easily with sh).

The issue is simple : when I try to insert a $variable in my regex, the regex fails.
But it works fine when I replace the $variable by its actual value.
I NEED to use multiple Ksh regex with the $variable in, how to do it ?

Exemple 1 regex works echo "hourra" :

```
#!/bin/ksh
file=BEFORE_ONE_AFTER
name="(ONE|TWO)"

if [[ $file = @(BEFORE_(ONE|TWO)_AFTER) ]] ; then
echo "hurra!"
fi
```

Exemple 2 regex fails no echo:

```
#!/bin/ksh
file=BEFORE_ONE_AFTER
name="(ONE|TWO)"

if [[ $file = @(BEFORE_${name}_AFTER) ]] ; then
    echo "ohde!"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me on ubuntu:

```
efs@efs-VirtualBox:~$ cat x.sh
#!/bin/ksh
file=BEFORE_ONE_AFTER
name="(ONE|TWO)"

if [[ $file = @(BEFORE_${name}_AFTER) ]] ; then
  echo "ohde!"
fi
efs@efs-VirtualBox:~$ ./x.sh
ohde!
efs@efs-VirtualBox:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Using AIX ksh, add quotes around the parameter.

```
 #!/bin/ksh
 file=BEFORE_ONE_AFTER
 name="(ONE|TWO)"

 if [[ $file = @(BEFORE_"${name}"_AFTER) ]] ; then
     echo "ohde!"
 fi
```

```
$./test.sh  
ohde!  
$
```